# Flutter: How do I set the state of a Switch with sharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

How do I read the sharedPreference and set the switch with the result?

I am trying to deveop a list of items that can be checked off, and save the state of each switch using sharedPreferences.

I think I am storing the values, but I cannot get the code to read the sharedPreference file and set the switch

I have searched but my problem is quite unique and I cannot find a solution.

```
class CheckList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckListState createState() => _CheckListState();
}
bool isSwitched = false;

class _CheckListState extends State<CheckList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 35.0),
        child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Text('Check List', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,     color: Colors.green), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CheckItem('Deposit Paid', 'Deposit'),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CheckItem('Balance Paid', 'Balance'),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CheckItem('Uploaded Team Name','Team'),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CheckItem('Uploaded Charity','Charity'),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CheckItem('Sent Copy of Leader Passport','Passport'),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CheckItem('Log book in Team Members name','LogBook'),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CheckItem('Rally Insurance Printed out','Insurance'),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CheckItem('MOT printed out', 'Mot'),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CheckItem('Fueled up and Ready to go', 'Ready'),
                SizedBox(height: 10),

              ],
            )
        ),
    );
  }
}



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class CheckItem extends StatefulWidget {
  CheckItem(this.txt, this.checkKey);
  final String txt;
  final String checkKey;


  @override
  _CheckItemState createState() => _CheckItemState();
}

bool isSwitched = false;


class _CheckItemState extends State<CheckItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 25),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: Text(
            widget.txt,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'sans pro',
              color: Colors.white,
              letterSpacing: 2.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          )),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
          ),
          Switch(
            value: isSwitched,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                isSwitched = value;

                putShared(widget.checkKey, value);
              });
        },
        activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        activeColor: Colors.green,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void putShared(String key, bool val) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool(key, val);
}

Future getShared(String key) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool val = prefs.getBool(key);
  return val;
}
```

The code seems to work, however I cannot be sure as I am unable to read the shared preferences and set the switchs.

Comment: This is too much unrelated code, and the question itself is rather broad. You already have `getShared` & `putShared` methods to work with `SharedPreferences`. What seems to be the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Considering your code.
You need to load the recorded value every time you use setState, so it was necessary to change the construction of Switch to Futurebuilder because of SharePreference to be async. And change getShared() to return a default value 'false' if there isn't sharePreferences yet.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CheckList(),
    );
  }
}

class CheckList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckListState createState() => _CheckListState();
}

class _CheckListState extends State<CheckList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Card(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 35.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Text(
                'Check List',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.green),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CheckItem('Deposit Paid', 'Deposit'),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CheckItem('Balance Paid', 'Balance'),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CheckItem('Uploaded Team Name', 'Team'),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CheckItem('Uploaded Charity', 'Charity'),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CheckItem('Sent Copy of Leader Passport', 'Passport'),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CheckItem('Log book in Team Members name', 'LogBook'),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CheckItem('Rally Insurance Printed out', 'Insurance'),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CheckItem('MOT printed out', 'Mot'),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CheckItem('Fueled up and Ready to go', 'Ready'),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}

class CheckItem extends StatefulWidget {
  CheckItem(this.txt, this.checkKey);
  final String txt;
  final String checkKey;

  @override
  _CheckItemState createState() => _CheckItemState();
}

class _CheckItemState extends State<CheckItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 25),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: Text(
            widget.txt,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'sans pro',
              color: Colors.white,
              letterSpacing: 2.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          )),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
          ),

          ///////// CHANGES HERE
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getShared(widget.checkKey),
              initialData: false,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Switch(
                  value: snapshot.data,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      putShared(widget.checkKey, value);
                    });
                  },
                  activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                );
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void putShared(String key, bool val) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool(key, val);
}

Future getShared(String key) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  ///////// CHANGES HERE
  bool val = prefs.getBool(key) == null ? false : (prefs.getBool(key));
  return val;
}
```